# How to run keytool and jarasigner in php on web server

Tags: php, android, ant, keytool, jarsigner

I want a `php` script to generate `apk` for Android with creating `keystore` and assign with `jarasigner`.

The command for this task:

1. ant
2. keytool
3. jarsigner

This command executes in local PC with Java and Android installed in php script. So how to run this command on web server when hosting this script on hosting server?

```
function generate_apk($apk_data = array()) {
    global $log_txt;
    $apk_cmd = "ant -f \"{$apk_data['project_path']}/build.xml\" release\n";

    $keystore_cmd  =  "keytool -genkey -dname 'cn=kamlesh jadeja, ou=JavaSoft, o=Sun, c=US' -storepass {$apk_data['password']}";
    $keystore_cmd .= " -alias business -keypass {$apk_data['password']} -keystore {$apk_data['keystore_path']}{$apk_data['keystore']} -validity 36500 \n";

    $jarassign  = "jarsigner -verbose -digestalg SHA1";
    $jarassign .= " -storepass {$apk_data['password']} -keypass {$apk_data['password']} -keystore {$apk_data['keystore_path']}{$apk_data['keystore']}";
    $jarassign .= " {$apk_data['project_path']}bin/{$apk_data['apk_name']}-release-unsigned.apk business\n";

    exec($apk_cmd);
    exec($keystore_cmd);    
    exec($jarassign);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have achieve this but using a Virtual private server, where I have installed JDK and Android SDK.

You wont be able to run any of those external commands unless your server supports that functionality.

Consider hosting your application in a VPS (Amazon, OVH, etc). I use OVH and it's very cheap and simple.

I hope this info helps.

Regards!